# Custom exception wrong inheritance

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, sonarqube

I have created custom base exception that extends `Exception` class. Later on I'm extending `MyBaseException` class by another - this time specyfic exception class. And I now have problem with one of SonarQube - to be specyfic with "**Classes named like "Exception" should extend "Exception" or a subclass**" rule. Class declarations looks like that:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;    
public class MyBaseException extends Exception {
    public MyBaseException(int code, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
        LOGGER.error("Exception with HttpStatus code: " + code + " Msg: "
            + message);
    }

    public MyBaseException(HttpStatus code, String message) {
        this(code.value(), message);
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    } 
}

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
public class SpecException extends MyBaseException {
    public SpecException (HttpStatus code, String message) {
        super(code, message);
    }

    public SpecException (int code, String message) {
        super(code, message);
    }
}
```

Problem is only with this `SpecException`. SonarQube don't see any issues with first inheritance. Hint given by SonarQube is: "**Rename this class to remove "Exception" or correct its inheritance.**" but I think inheritance is correct since I'm inheriting by subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: Does MyBaseException extend Exception? It sounds like it's complaining about that.

Comment: Yes, it extends Exception. This class is valid by sonar. Problem is with SpecException.

Comment: Yeah it's not really possible to tell without an actual minimum example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Now it should be better. Anyway it's all I have regarding this exception issue.

Comment: Is the bytecode of your base class provided to the analyzer via sonar.java.libraries property ? what is the version of the sonar java plugin ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where to find java plugin version. All I know is that it's sonar version 5.1. Currently I've fixed it by turning off this rule. bit dirty though...

Comment: you can see version of the java plugin in the update center of your SonarQube instance.

More importantly is how do you analyse your project ? maven or sonar-runner ? if the latter, how do you provide bytecode to the analysis. 
If the bytecode of MyBaseException (I suppose this class is not defined in the same file as SpecException) is not provided to the analyzer, then the type hierarchy is not properly resolved and you get this false positive.

Answer (score 4):

At this link someone says that Sonar 6.0 corrects this issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/iXxKGIYRZ1g.

> I have just realised Sonar v6.0 is out, the problem is gone after I
>   tested with the new version. Thank you Michael for your time.

It seems like it is a bug on previous versions of Sonar. It's well known that all exception classes in Java are named by convention ending with "Exception" and that they can have multiple levels so your code seems to be correct as soon as your upper level exception is extending the `Exception` class.